# Problems with text file appending in python

Tags: python, file, text, append

I am having python problems.

I have made a program to ask a user for their email address and it appends it to a text file, after doing some checks, everything is working fine, but it ends up with nothing in the text file, even though no errors show up.

My code is:

```
def main():
    print("Hello and welcome to customer email program!")

    count=0

    while count < 1:
        email=str(input("Email Address: "))
        if "@" in email:
            if email.islower == True:
                count=2
                with open("emails.txt", "a") as myfile:
                    myfile.write(email)
                print("File added to databse")
            else:
                email=email.lower()
                count=2
                with open("emails.txt", "a") as myfile:
                    myfile.write(email)
        else:
            print("That is not an email address, please try again.")
main()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. try using the full path of the file. 2. you can do `email.islower:` no need for the `== True`

Comment: To clarify, do the program print "File added to database" but when you are done there is a file in the local directory called "emails.txt" but its empty?

Comment: The first thing that pops up is you want to write email.islower() instead of email.islower.

Comment: @alfasin - relative paths are fine. its just the local directory when you run the script.

Comment: The script ran correctly for me, Python 3.2.3 on Ubuntu 12.04. Worth noting that you're not adding new lines, so all of the emails are on the same line, without any separating spaces.

Comment: did you want to write the emails line by line? Then you want `myfile.write(email + os.linesep)`.

Comment: On my machine, the script adds an address to the file as expected. Python 3.4.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: @alfasin - opening in append mode creates an empty file if it doesn't already exist. I'm checking to see if he's looking for the file in the right place!

Comment: Works on OSX with python 3.3

Comment: @tdelaney depends on the permission of the folder, isn't it ?

Comment: @alfasin - if he doesn't have permissions, an exception is raised, so its not that.

Comment: @tdelaney from my experience with people asking questions here, either an exception was raised and he didn't notice - or he's looking at a file in the wrong directory. Since (at least) 3 people confirmed that this script is working for them I vote to close it as "irreproducible".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should open the file and then CLOSE the file after you append to it:

```
def main() :
    print("Hello and welcome to customer email program!")

    done = False

    while not done :
        email = str(input("What's your email address? "))
        if "@" in email :
            if not email.lower() == email :
                email = email.lower()
            done = True
            f = open("emails.txt" "a")
            f.write(email)
            f.close()
        else :
            print("Please type in a valid email address, "+email+" isn't a valid email address")
main()
```

Does this fit your needs?